# What is nedeed to prove that the tangent space on a manifold is a vector space?

Tags: differential-geometry, equivalence-relations, tangent-spaces

I am currently working with the definition of tangent vectors being equivalence classes of curves. So $v =[\gamma]$ and $w=[\sigma]$ where $v,w$ are the vectors. I want to prove that the sum of this two equivalence class is also a equivalence class to give it the vector space structure.  We define the sum as:

$v+w= [\phi^{-1} \circ (\phi \circ \gamma + \phi \circ \sigma)]$

where $\phi$ is a chart. I understand that the curves can not be added when they belong to the manifold, that's why we first map then into the reals where that can be performed. So now that the sum is defined, how can I prove that is another class at the point $p$ on $M$. Is it enough to make sure that the map passes by $p$? The same questions goes for the multiplication by the scalar. Thanks

Comment: $\phi$ a chart from $M$ to $R$ and the other its inverse.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I did not know how to make composition properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that tangent space is a vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798409/proof-that-tangent-space-is-a-vector-space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having read your post more carefully, here's a one-sentence summary of your mistake: **you're trying to add (and scalar multiply) the curves in $\Bbb{R}^n$, rather than their velocities.** As you observed, adding the curves messes up things with the base points.

---

As a set, we have $T_pM$ is the set of equivalence classes of smooth curves, $[\gamma]$, where $\gamma$ is defined on some open interval containing $0$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$. Now, for any chart $(U,\phi)$ about the point $p$, consider the function $F_{\phi,p}:T_pM \to \Bbb{R}^n$ defined as
\begin{align}
F_{\phi,p}([\gamma]):= (\phi\circ \gamma)'(0).
\end{align}
This function is well-defined because of how the equivalence relation is defined. Notice the intuitive meaning: $\gamma$ is a curve with values in the manifold $M$, so if we use a chart, we can get a corresponding curve $\phi\circ \gamma$ with values in the Banach space (i.e a normed vector space) $\Bbb{R}^n$, and we know how calculus works in the setting of vector spaces. So, all this map $F_{\phi,p}$ does is it takes a curve $[\gamma]$ and maps it to the "velocity vector" $(\phi\circ \gamma)'(0)$. I hope this is intuitive (otherwise, just draw a few pictures to see where each object is).

Now, it is also easy to verify that $F_{\phi,p}$ is a bijective function; I leave it to you to verify that $G_{\phi,p}:\Bbb{R}^n\to T_pM$ defined as
\begin{align}
G_{\phi,p}(v):= [t\mapsto \phi^{-1}(\phi(p)+tv)]
\end{align}
is the inverse function. In words, what we're doing is we're taking a vector $v\in\Bbb{R}^n$, and considering the straight line $t\mapsto \phi(p)+tv$. This is a curve based at the point $\phi(p)$, in the direction $v$. Since $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, it follows that for small enough values of $t$, we have $\phi(p)+tv\in \phi(U)=\text{domain}(\phi^{-1})$, hence we can consider the equivalence class of the curve $t\mapsto \phi^{-1}(\phi(p)+tv)$.

---

So, what has all this extra notation yielded? Well, we have a bijective function $F_{\phi,p}:T_pM\to \Bbb{R}^n$, and of course, $\Bbb{R}^n$ is a vector space, so by basic linear algebra, we can "pull back" the vector space structure of $\Bbb{R}^n$ so as to make $F_{\phi,p}$ a linear isomorphism. Explicitly, what I mean is that we can define addition and scalar multiplication $+_{\phi}$ and $\cdot_{\phi}$ (I put the subscript because everything is chart-dependent so far) as follows:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
[\gamma_1]+_{\phi} [\gamma_2]&:= F_{\phi,p}^{-1}\bigg(F_{\phi,p}([\gamma_1])+
F_{\phi,p}([\gamma_2])\bigg)\\
c\cdot_{\phi}[\gamma]&:= F_{\phi,p}^{-1}\bigg(c\cdot F_{\phi,p}([\gamma])\bigg)
\end{cases}
\end{align}

If you unwind all the definitions, then
\begin{align}
c\cdot_{\phi}[\gamma_1]+_{\cdot}[\gamma_2]= [t\mapsto \phi^{-1}\left(\phi(p) + t(c\cdot (\phi\circ \gamma_1)'(0)+(\phi\circ \gamma_2)'(0))\right)]
\end{align}
Hopefully, the idea is clear enough: you have a bijection, so you just push everything forward, do the computations in $\Bbb{R}^n$, then bring everything back to $T_pM$, and that's how addition and scalar multiplication is defined. I leave it to you that all the vector space axioms are satisfied and that $F_{\phi,p}$ is a linear isomorphism etc.

One final thing to note is that so far the addition and scalar multiplication have been defined using a particular chart $(U,\phi)$, but actually, it is a simple chain rule exercise to verify that if you have a different chart $(V,\psi)$, then $+_{\phi}=+_{\psi}$ and $\cdot_{\phi}=\cdot_{\psi}$, so the vector space structure on $T_pM$ is actually chart-independent, hence we just denote it as $+$ and $\cdot$ as usual. I leave it to you to unwind definitions, use chain rule etc to verify this. If you have trouble, let me know, maybe I can elaborate more.

Comment: Thank you so much for the elaborated answer. I have a question. I'm following Isham's book of differential geometry for physicists. In the definition of the sum, why appears velocity terms. According to the book there are only curves terms.

Comment: @OMARMEDINABAUTISTA i don't have the book with me but adding the curves directly only works if you assume that you chart is special in the sense that $\phi(p)=0\in\Bbb{R}^n$. In this case, coincides with mine because

Comment: In this case, both approaches are equivalent because (let's work with addition only) we have that the curves $f_1 = \phi^{-1}\circ (\phi\circ \gamma_1 + \phi\circ \gamma_2)$ and the curve $f_2(t)=\phi^{-1}\bigg(t\cdot ((\phi\circ\gamma_1)'(0) + (\phi\circ\gamma_2)'(0))\bigg)$ are equivalent, i.e $(\phi\circ f_1)'(0)=(\phi\circ f_2)'(0)$. So, the definition I wrote above (if you assume $\phi(p)=0$) reduces to $[\gamma_1]+[\gamma_2]:= [f_2] = [f_1]$, but $[f_1]$ is exactly what adding the curves means (the definition you wrote in your post).

Comment: The thing is I personally don't like to assume additional things about my charts, which is why I gave the above definition which works in the general case even for $\phi(p)\neq 0$ (I mean really this is no loss of generality... I just rather not lol).

Comment: Thank you so much. That clarifies it.

Comment: Hello! I have a question. Can the proof of $T_{p} M$ being a vector space be called appropiate if only works for certain charts? Thanks

Comment: @OMARMEDINABAUTISTA your definition holds for every chart such that $\phi(p)=0$, so it really is valid. But of course, with your definition, you shouldn't then try to calculate the sum $[\gamma_1]+[\gamma_2]$ using a chart $(U,\phi)$ with $\phi(p)\neq 0$. This would be nonsense, because your definition explicitly requires $\phi(p)=0$.

Comment: This has been very interesting. I have a problem. I find hard to believe that the map $F$ is surjective.

Comment: That all vectors in $R^{n}$ can find a class in the point $p \in M$.

Comment: @OMARMEDINABAUTISTA I even gave you the explicit formula for the inverse function which is $G_{\phi,p}$... i.e if $v\in\Bbb{R}^n$ then the corresponding equivalence class is $G_{\phi,p}(v)=[t\mapsto \phi^{-1}(\phi(p)+tv)]$. All you have to do is unwind definitions to check $F_{\phi,p}\circ G_{\phi,p}=\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^n}$ and $G_{\phi,p}\circ F_{\phi,p}=\text{id}_{T_pM}$.